# How can I update or insert multiple rows with ecto? (Upsert)

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

How can I either insert or update multiple rows with different values using Ecto with Postgres?

If I have a schema/struct: `%Counter{key: String.t(), count: integer()}`

How can I insert or update multiple entries? If the record does not exist I want to insert it, but if it does exist I want to increment the value.

```
[
  %{key: "questions:asked", count: 1},
  %{key: "questions:answered", count: 1},
  %{key: "ads:viewed", count: 3}
]
```

`Ecto.Repo.insert_all` with :on_replace looks like it should work, but I want unique values for each row.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Ecto.Repo.insert_all`, but you must provide a query and take advantage of Postgresql's `excluded` table available in the conflict action.

```
upsert_query =
  Counter
  |> where([o], o.key == fragment("EXCLUDED.key"))
  |> update(inc: [count: fragment("EXCLUDED.count")])

Repo.insert_all(Counter, records,
  on_conflict: upsert_query,
  conflict_target: [:key],
  returning: false
)
```

The excluded values are the values that you passed in represented as a temporary table only available in the on conflict.

It should be noted that this can be used with set instead of inc if you wish to set a particular value.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiomatic way to perform upserts that set specific column values with `insert_all` ([under the hood](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/6dd7df5ba5f3bb1a9901a7eeb3f5dbc2a846ab8c/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L219-L225) Ecto adapters use the special on_conflict EXCLUDED table)

```
  first_pass = [
    %{key: "questions:asked", count: 1},
    %{key: "questions:answered", count: 1},
    %{key: "ads:viewed", count: 3}
  ]

  Repo.insert_all(CustomerLog, first_pass,
    on_conflict: {:replace, [:count]},
    conflict_target: :key
  )

  second_pass = [
    %{key: "questions:asked", count: 2},
    %{key: "questions:answered", count: 2},
    %{key: "ads:viewed", count: 4}
  ]

  Repo.insert_all(CustomerLog, second_pass,
    on_conflict: {:replace, [:count]},
    conflict_target: :key
  )
```

```
  # After adding the updating the counts reflect
  # the second pass values
  
  IO.inspect(Repo.all(CustomerLog))
  
  > Repo.all(CustomerLog) #=> [
    %CustomerLog{
      __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "customer_log">,
      id: 4,
      key: "questions:asked",
      count: 2
    },
    %CustomerLog{
      __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "customer_log">,
      id: 5,
      key: "questions:answered",
      count: 2
    },
    %CustomerLog{
      __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "customer_log">,
      id: 6,
      key: "ads:viewed",
      count: 4
    }
  ]
```

Note: the above assumes there is a unique index on the `:key` column, so anyone implementing this pattern will need to do that in their migration.

```
  ...
  create unique_index(:customer_log, [:key])
  ...
```

Note: you can reference multiple fields in `conflict_target` for compound indexes.